# IntegrityError: update or delete on table "products_product" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to delete from Django admin all the products which are stored in PostgresSQL database but getting that error for one product:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/products/product/
update or delete on table "products_product" violates foreign key constraint "products_curateprodu_product_id_ec2cf1ec_fk_products_" on table "products_curateproducts_products"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(72) is still referenced from table "products_curateproducts_products".
```

I am not able to figure out why it shows that error while under Curranted Products in Django admin I don´t have any products. At least it won´t show there any, just 0 Curated Products.

Code is here for the Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True,
            null=True,
            upload_to=download_media_location,
            storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PROTECTED_ROOT))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,  unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=9.99, null=True)
    sale_active =models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
        ordering = ['title']
```

and code for Curated Products model:

```
class CuratedProducts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Curated Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Curated Products'
```

Update, using:

Django 3.0.5,
psycopg2-binary 2.8.5

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I am using Django 3.0.5

Comment: @thatguy. Your edit made the error message less readable, please return it the style I had it in.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Rolled back. However, please consider [disabling syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98226/can-we-add-how-to-disable-syntax-highlighting-to-the-editing-help-faq) in the preformatted text, because this is **not code**, but an error message and that makes it less readable, too.

Comment: Actually the error message contains code and having it highlighted brought my attention to the issue right away. The goal of this site as I understand it is to come up with answers not be overly pedantic.

Comment: Was there a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is showing:

```
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(72) is still referenced from table "products_curateproducts_products".
```

Note the name `curateproducts_products`. That does match the model you show. There is another table in the mix.

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianKlaver. 

How do I find what table is in the mix? CuratedProduct.products takes the Product model as an input for products (products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)) and that should be the only model with what it's linked. 

How do I find it out and how I can delete that product what's not showing up in admin under Curated Products, but shows up as an error? Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Well first I would look in the database, using psql, for the table to determine its structure.  Aah, missed the ManyToManyField. That would generate an intermediary table. Still I would look in the database to sort out the relationships and data present as that is where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. I will try to check based on what you said.